# Shrinking amount of space is very low Windows 11

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm trying to shrink my C drive but I only get a certain amount I'm allow to use. This is what i've tried:

-Turning off system protection of the drive

-Cleaning the drive with disk clean up.

-Turning off paging file in Virtual memory

This is the amount I can use:
[image]

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: You can't shrink data that needs to be there. If you've already gone through the basic disk cleanup functions, you cannot magically make more space on a disk with a finite and defined amount of storage. Given the information you have provided us, there is not a problem here that Shrink or Cleanup is the answer to.

Comment: NTFS has a bunch of data (metadata) that is particularly difficult to move. One such "file" is `$BITMAP` - on one of my systems it's sitting at about the 300GB mark (out of 350GB) which means it's impossible to shrink the partition below 300GB - there are 3rd party utilities that claim to be able to move them, however, I would not recommend them (unless you have a good backup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to see what is taking up space, e.g. with [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/). If it's your data, you'll need to move it to another disk or partition, or to completely delete it.

**If** you remove files, it **might** be possible to [shrink](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-support-how-to-re-partition-without-destroying-the-data-c3d64de0-4672-b21f-de4e-b4908fb35ae3) the size of C:. However, if some essential system files are located *near the end* of that disk partition, and cannot be moved, then shrink will fail. You would need to delete the entire volume, **effectively destroying the WINDOWS OS and all your data**, then shrink it and reinstall Windows on the smaller volume and reinstall all applications and data.